# Макрос сохранения писем в формате HTML

Tags: html, vba

Нужна помощь в написание макроса. Что бы он сохранял письма от определённого адресата в формате `HTML` т.е если письмо пришло с картинкой макрос должен сохранить её в месте с картинкой, и что бы была возможность просмотреть письмо в браузере. Пытался сам сделать но опыта не хватает мой код ниже прошу помочь

```
Sub SaveAsTXT() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim objItem As Object 

 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then 
 Set objItem = myItem.CurrentItem 
 strname = objItem.Subject 
 'Prompt the user for confirmation 
 Dim strPrompt As String 
 strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item? " & _ 
 "If a file with the same name already exists, " & _ 
 "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
 If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
 objItem.SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & strname & ".html", olTXT 
 End If 
 Else 
 MsgBox "There is no current active inspector." 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов реализации задачи следующий:

1. Анализ адресатов письма которых требуется сохранять в формате HTML производим с помощью встроенного механизма правил MS Outlook;
2. Сохранение писем в формате HTML производим с помощью макроса.

Подробно.

1.Создаем код макроса, который сохраняет письма в формате HTML. Подробности в комментариях:

```
Option Explicit
' ограничения макроса
' файлы /папки не проверяются на наличие
' для корректной работы файлы / папки не должны быть созданы на диске
Sub MailSaveToHTML(myItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim sName As String             ' имя папки, имя файла = теме письма
    Dim sSaveFolder As String       ' папка для сохранения письма в формате HTML
    Dim sFilesFolder As String      ' если письмо содержит присоединенные файлы, то сохраняем в папке, которая создаеся по умолчанию в виде <sName.files>
    Dim oAttchmnt As Outlook.Attachment

    sName = myItem.Subject
    sName = sReplacedSymbols(sName, "_")        ' функция заменяет недопустимые символы в именах файлов/папок
    sSaveFolder = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE")) + "\Documents\"
    sFilesFolder = sSaveFolder + sName + ".files"
    ' обрабатываем только почтовые сообщения
    If TypeName(myItem) = "MailItem" Then
        ' если картинка внедрена в письмо, то будет сохранена в папку sFilesFolder для отображения в файле HTML
        myItem.SaveAs sSaveFolder + sName + ".htm", olHTML
        ' записываем все присоединенные файлы в папку sFilesFolder
        ' если картинка внедрена в письмо, то перовначально будет сохранена с именем image001.jpg (и. т. 002, 003 если несколько)
        ' и повторно как вложение
        For Each oAttchmnt In myItem.Attachments
           oAttchmnt.SaveAsFile sFilesFolder + "\" + oAttchmnt.FileName
           'MsgBox (oAttchmnt.FileName)
        Next
    Else
        'все прочие сообщения (задачи, встречи и т.п. не обрабатываются)
        MsgBox ("Сообщение не является почтовым")
    End If
End Sub

' код функции замены символов недопустимых в именях файлов/папок взят с
' http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/714054-macro-save-selected-outlook-2010-email-folder-msg-file.html

Function sReplacedSymbols(sStr As String, sSmbl As String) As String
    sReplacedSymbols = sStr
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, "/", sSmbl)
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, "\", sSmbl)
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, ":", sSmbl)
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, "?", sSmbl)
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, Chr(34), sSmbl)
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, "<", sSmbl)
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, ">", sSmbl)
    sReplacedSymbols = Replace(sReplacedSymbols, "|", sSmbl)
End Function
```

2.Создаем правило, которое запускает макрос по определенным условиям (в нашем случае от определенных адресатов):

2.1.Главная-Правила-Создавать правило...

[image: Главная-Правила-Создавать правило...]

2.2.Создание-Правила.

[image: Создание правила]

2.3.Мастер правил-Запустить скрипт. Выбираем из списка скрипт MailSaveToHTML.

[image: Мастер правил-Запустить скрипт]

2.4.Мастер правил-Завершение настройки правил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.5.Правила и оповещения

[image: Правила и оповещения]

3. Варианты использования:

3.1.Активировать правило. В момент получения писем от адресатов, указанных в Правиле, будет выполняться макрос. При тестировании получения писем с почтового ящика yandex.ru с вложенными файлами даже при незначительных их объемах не происходит экспорт т.к. макрос отрабатывает быстрее чем файлы загружаются.
Как вариант решения - установить задержку выполнения макроса.

3.2.Например, принудительно применить правило для принятых и непрочитанных писем. Макрос отрабатывает корректно.
[image: Применить правило]

Comment: большое спасибо добрый человек.

Comment: Подскажите, как изменить скрипт, чтобы сохранялись только письма в html, без вложений по папкам?
и было бы не плохо добавить в название дату, когда пришло письмо на почту.
Попытки самостоятельно отредактировать не увенчались успехом..